# Spring Boot / VertX call timeout in openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift

I'm trying to call a vertx service from a spring boot service and both services are deployed in openshift; but got this exception:

> 2020-04-28 03:25:12.556 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://vertx-service:8080/":  Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)] with root cause
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
>   ...

This is the code used to call the service from spring boot application:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
String url = "http://vertx-service:8080/"; // I'm using discovery pattern here
String response = template.getForEntity(url, String.class).getBody());
```

This is the vertx application's code:

```
public class SimpleWebVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.get("/").handler(this::handleGet);

        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
    }

    private void handleGet(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        routingContext.vertx().<String>executeBlocking(future -> {
            String response;
            CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                    () -> {
                        String res = "Hello from VertX! Server name: "
                        + System.getenv().getOrDefault("HOSTNAME", "unknown");
                        return res;
                    });
            try {
                response = cf.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                response = e.getMessage();
            }
            future.complete(response);
        }, false, result -> {
            routingContext.response()
                    .putHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                    .end(result.result());
        });
    }
}
```

Additional information: Also have developed an api-gateway service using swagger to call the services and got success from the spring boot service but response (fallback) from the vertx service.

Versions used:
Spring Boot 2.2, Vertx 3.3, Minishift 3.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with just

```
String url = "http://vertx-service/";
```

The port 8080 is not required in your url. Assuming that `vertx-service` is the name of another service object deployed on Openshift. Also check the pod details of `vertx-service` whether the port is exposed in the container.

In openshift, the service name acts as the load balancer for all the pod instances of a container image.

Comment: You're right!. Vertx-service port configuration expects port 80. Googling searching time has finally over! :) Thanks man! (y)